# How to redirect to multiple view through next and previous button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a next and previous button on footer which is on index.html file. My code structure is as below-

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body ng-controller="myController">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content"><ng-view></ng-view></div>
<div id="footer">
   <button type="button" id="next" ng-click="nextPage()">Next</button>
   <button type="button" id="prev" ng-click="prevPage()">Previous</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On click of Next and previous button, my page content should redirect to new view in the content. I have used ui-view to redirect to different view.
But in controller part it only redirect to 1.html page. After again when I click it does not redirect to 2.html page

I need to redirect to different page(1.html,2.html,3.html,4.html) on click of each next button. 
Please let me know how it can be possible.

Comment: please post also the code for `nextPage()`, `previousPage()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an issue with your code. Since you are using `ui.router`, any interaction with the `$stateProvider` and `$state`s need to happen using the `ui-view` directive but you have used `ng-view` and so your code won't work. Change it as below:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body ng-controller="myController">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <button type="button" id="next" ng-click="nextPage()">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prev" ng-click="prevPage()">Previous</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using angular [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body ng-controller="myController">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content"><ng-view></ng-view></div>
<div id="footer">
   <button type="button" id="next" ng-click="go('/NextPageUrl')">Next</button>
   <button type="button" id="prev" ng-click="go('/PrevPageUrl')">Previous</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**In controller:**

```
$scope.go = function ( path ) {
  $location.path( path );
};
```

Comment: When using `ui.router` you should not use `ng-view`

Comment: You should be using <div ui-view></div>